# c++ map not returning value

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Why does my map inside Test does not return its value? What's wrong with this?

```
class Test{ //Test.h
public:
  std::map< char*,  int> mm;

  Test();
  void set();
  int get( char*);
};

Test::Test(){ //Test.cpp
}

void Test::set(){
  mm["aaa"] = 24;
}

int Test::get( char* n){
  return mm[n];
}

int main(){ //main.cpp
   Test *test = new Test();
   test->set();

   //this returns 0 instead of 24
   printf("From Test: %d\n", test->get("aaa"));
   printf("From Test: %d\n", test->mm["aaa"]);

   delete test;

   //this map works
   std::map<char*, int> mm;
   mm["a"] = 54;

   printf("Local: %d\n", mm["a"]);

   return 0;
}
```

Needs extra text to post >.<

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: http://ideone.com/l9XKsk, the output is correct?

Comment: yes, but if I run it here it displays 0 instead of 24

Comment: what's your compiler? I tried VS2012, Gcc4.7.2, gcc 4.3.4, all print `24 24 54`

Comment: nevermind, I replaced char* with string. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because you use char* pointer as a key. For two literals addresses will be different. To make map work properly you must use some other string class which has operator< defined. std::string, for instance.

Comment: I don't actually get it... "For two literals addresses will be different"?? Further explanation would help if that's ok. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Map uses operator< to order items. For char* literals addresses may be different even if literals are equal. Basically we can have two literals "aaaa" at address 0x12345678 and "aaaa" at 0xffffffff.

Answer (score 2):

This type:

```
std::map< char*,  int>;
```

Says that key is a pointer, which is NOT a string. That means it is a pointer. To understand it better, consider this:

```
char* p1, *p2;
p1 = "abc";
p2=  "abc";

if (p1==p2) // THIS IS INVALID
```

Why the last line is invalid? Well, both are pointers, and pointing to some memory location, right? Assume compiler doesn't optimize the string constants, and thus addresses of `"abc"` *and* `"abc"` would be different. And hence the comparison will fail.

You would say, you'd use `strcmp`, instead. Exactly! That's the whole point, `map::find` doesn't know if it as to use string-comparison routine! It just compares two pointers, and you get the invalid result. So, better use a string class (`std::string`), or pass the comparator to the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

//this returns 0 instead of 24

printf("From Test: %d\n", test->get("aaa"));

because the memory address of "aaa"  is different the map you store,

mm["aaa"] = 24  and  get("aaa")  is no a same pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a pointer value as a map/hash's key.
Key type, maybe you can use std::string.

```
map<string, int> mm; // this would work.
```

PS:

```
p1 = "abc";
p2=  "abc";
```

I think, whether p1 equals p2, it's hard to say, it's up to compiler's implementation.